# Embedding YouTube videos into a Google Slides presentation

Tags: youtube, google-slides

Is it possible to embed a YouTube video into a Google Slides presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Slides, use `Insert → Video`. You can then embed a YouTube video either by searching or by video URL.

[image: embed video by searching]